# Powershell Array of hashtables

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

For example, I have 3 hashtables with different key-values:

```
$Queue1 = @{
    QueueName = 'MyTestQueue1'
    LockDuration = 'PT1M1'
    AutoDeleteOnIdle = 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S1'
}

$Queue2 = @{
    QueueName = 'MyTestQueue2'
    LockDuration = 'PT1M2'
    AutoDeleteOnIdle = 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S2'
}

$Queue3 = @{
    QueueName = 'MyTestQueue3'
    LockDuration = 'PT1M3'
    AutoDeleteOnIdle = 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S3'
}
```

Is it possible to combine them in the array and use each key-value inside the foreach?

```
foreach($hashtable in $Hashtables){
    
    $QueueName = $hashtable.QueueName
    $LockDuration = $hashtable.LockDuration 
    $AutoDeleteOnIdle = $hashtable.AutoDeleteOnIdle
    # Some code here
    }
```

Comment: How about `$Hashtables = @($Queue1, $Queue2, $Queue3)`, does this work?

Comment: Thanks! Was unable to find such an example. You can arrange this as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare an array, as portrayed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.2), you use this syntax:

```
$variable = @(element1, element2, element3, ...)
```

so to create an array for your queues:

```
$Hashtables = @($Queue1, $Queue2, $Queue3)
```

you can also split it over multiple lines, and in that variant the commas are optional:

```
$Hashtables = @(
    $Queue1
    $Queue2
    $Queue3
)
```